# Por que o retorno é 115?

Tags: php

A pergunta é bem explicativa. Porque o retorno no último `%s` é 115?

```
$key = 0;
$count = 33;
$id = 1;
echo printf("%s de %s - ID: %s", ++$key, $count, $id);
// 1 de 33 - ID: 115
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Porque o retorno de `printf` é a quantidade de caracteres escritos, você pode checar isso na [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php#refsect1-function.printf-returnvalues).

O problema do seu código é que ele faz **duas impressões**: a do `printf` e a do `echo`. Provavelmente você queria fazer apenas o `printf`.

```php
$key = 0;
$count = 33;
$id = 1;
printf("%s de %s - ID: %s", ++$key, $count, $id);
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://replit.com/@jfbueno/ptso425297)

Comment: ps: aproveitando, no caso se precisar do echo mesmo, use o `sprintf`

Comment: #funfact: na [documentação em português](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.printf.php) o retorno da função é `void`.

Answer (score 0):

O `printf` já imprime um output na tela, logo em seguida o `echo` escreve o retorno do `printf`, que é o tamanho da string imprimida.

Utilize sem o `echo` que terá o resultado esperado:

```
$key = 0;
$count = 33;
$id = 1;

printf("%s de %s - ID: %s", ++$key, $count, $id);
// 1 de 33 - ID: 1
```

Veja [funcionando](https://3v4l.org/D1UBk).

Ou então use o `sprintf` para retornar o valor e exibir com `echo` ao invés de imprimi-lo diretamente:

```
<?php

$key = 0;
$count = 33;
$id = 1;

echo sprintf("%s de %s - ID: %s", ++$key, $count, $id);
```

Veja [funcionando](https://3v4l.org/thmJn).